# Data Sync for Universal Windows App(desktop) Sqlite

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, azure, uwp

I am currently working on a windows universal app project(deskptop App), what i want to do is store data in my uwp app using sqlite database and be able to sync this data to a sql database located on azure, i went came across this online 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1/
but it seems applicable to sqlcompact and sql to sql on azure.
Please can any one help wiith how i can sync my uwp sqlite database with sql database on azure.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can sync my uwp sqlite database with sql database on azure.

You could use [Azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop). The mobile apps have the "Offline sync" feature:

> You can sync dataset automatically with the back-end data, including conflict-resolution support.

For more details about "Offline sync" please reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync).
For how to create a UWP mobile app please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started#configure-the-server-project).

In your scenario, since you already have a SqlServer on azure, so when you are following the tutorial, after created the backend, in the step of [Configure the server project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started#configure-the-server-project), you can instead choose "Use an existing database".

After the client mobile app created successfully, then you need to [Enable offline sync for your Windows app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data). The sample just showed how to use the SQLite as the local store. Using [`PushAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileservicesynccontextextensions.pushasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_MobileServiceSyncContextExtensions_PushAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MobileServices_Sync_IMobileServiceSyncContext_) method to push tables to the backend which is configured the SQL Server to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much, u a life saver